# MYSQL self join get row based on MAX and having

Tags: mysql, sql, select, self-join, having

I need to COUNT rows from 2 tables and only get the rows with highest `g_event_id` if `events.event_id IN (30, 31, 32, 33)`. Only take rows in account where `events.event_id` is 30-33.

SQL Fiddle: [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b16f66/6)

My tables:

```
 CREATE TABLE event_parties
 (`g_event_id` int, `agent_id` int)
;

INSERT INTO event_parties
(`g_event_id`, `agent_id`)
VALUES
(2917, '2'),
(2918, '2'),
(2919, '2'),
(3067, '3'),
(3078, '3'),
(3079, '1'),
(3082, '1'),
(3917, '2'),
(3918, '2'),
(3919, '2'),
(4067, '3'),
(4078, '3'),
(4079, '1'),
(5067, '3'),
(5078, '3'),
(5079, '1'),
(6067, '3'),
(6078, '3'),
(6079, '1'),
(7067, '3'),
(7078, '3'),
(7079, '1'),
(8067, '3'),
(8078, '3'),
(8079, '1')

;
CREATE TABLE events
(`g_event_id` int, `event_id` int, `event_time` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO events
(`g_event_id`, `event_id`, `event_time`)
 VALUES
(2917, '29', '2016-10-19 15:24:25'),
(2918, '31', '2016-10-19 15:24:28'),
(2919, '21', '2016-10-19 15:29:46'),
(3067, '29', '2016-10-20 15:33:46'),
(3078, '23', '2016-10-21 15:29:46'),
(3079, '29', '2016-10-20 15:34:46'),
(3082, '30', '2016-10-21 15:42:46'),
(3917, '29', '2016-10-19 15:24:25'),
(3918, '31', '2016-10-19 15:24:28'),
(3919, '21', '2016-10-19 15:29:46'),
(4067, '29', '2016-10-20 15:33:46'),
(4078, '23', '2016-10-21 15:29:46'),
(4079, '29', '2016-10-20 15:34:46'),
(5067, '29', '2016-10-20 15:33:46'),
(5078, '23', '2016-10-21 15:29:46'),
(5079, '29', '2016-10-20 15:34:46'),
(6067, '29', '2016-10-20 15:33:46'),
(6078, '23', '2016-10-21 15:29:46'),
(6079, '29', '2016-10-20 15:34:46'),
(7067, '29', '2016-10-20 15:33:46'),
(7078, '23', '2016-10-21 15:29:46'),
(7079, '29', '2016-10-20 15:34:46'),
(8067, '29', '2016-10-20 15:33:46'),
(8078, '23', '2016-10-21 15:29:46'),
(8079, '29', '2016-10-20 15:34:46')

;
```

The select is suppose to give me the status of an Callcenter Agent, i want to count how many agents (agent_id) in each state (event_id). As the table "events" is just events of the agents i only need to count the latest (with highest value) g_event_id of each agent_id and tricky part is that i only want to count where event_id IN (30, 31, 32, 32, 33).
So basicly, select rows with highest g_event_id (and event_id IN (30, 31, 32, 33)) for each agent_id.
I need an JOIN between these two tables with `g_event_id` as the ID. The field g_event_id is the key and only appears once. I need all fields in table `events` and I need the row with highest `g_event_id` or with highest `event_time`. 
Like this:

```
event_id   N_events
--------   ----------
    31         1
    30         1
```

I have this select so far:

```
SELECT event_id,
COUNT(events.event_id) AS N_events
FROM event_parties 
INNER JOIN events USING (g_event_id)
LEFT JOIN event_parties AS later_event
ON (later_event.agent_id = event_parties.agent_id 
  AND later_event.g_event_id > event_parties.g_event_id)
WHERE later_event.g_event_id IS NULL AND event_parties.agent_id != 0 AND     events.`event_id` IN (30,31,32,33)
GROUP BY events.event_id
```

Problem with this select above is that it will only give me the rows with highest `g_event_id`, i want to only select rows having `events.event_id` = (30, 31, 32, 33) and then count the rows with highest `g_event_id`

Been trying to use `having` after the GROUP (`HAVING events.event_id IN (30,31,32,33)`) without any success.

Comment: The fiddle isn't working for me, so I cannot check: is `g_event_id` your primary key? I assume not, otherwise your count would be 1 or 0, right? Also, your select-list (4 columns) doesn't fit your requested result (2 columns) or your `group by` (1 column + 1 count). Also I don't really understand what you mean by "I need the row with highest g_event_id or with highest event_time" - this describes potentially 2 rows, which row do you want? So: could you add the exact result you want from that data? And example data that is more clear (e.g. more than 1 identical g_event_id) and the table?

Comment: Updated the Fiddle [link] (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b16f66/6).
Also updated above with more data.

The select is suppose to give me the status of an Callcenter Agent, i want to count how many agents (agent_id) in each state (event_id). As the table "events" is just events on the agents i only need to count th elatest event_id of each agent and tricky part is that i only want to count where event_id IN (30, 31, 32, 32, 33)

Comment: You still didn't answer the important questions: can there be more than 1 row per `g_event_id` (that's what "more data" was suppose to show), and the exact result set you expect with that data you gave (because your description is still not clear enough).

Comment: Sorry, yes g_event_id is primary key (only one row per g_event_id).
The exact outcom i want is:

    event_id   N_events

    --------   ----------

     31         1
     30         1

Comment: I think I still miss the point. If `g_event_id` is the primary key, then there is at most one row with the highest `g_event_id`. Since you don't even want that id in the result, you can simply query `SELECT distinct event_id, 1 AS N_events FROM event_parties INNER JOIN events USING (g_event_id) WHERE events.event_id IN (30,31,32,33);`. If every row in event has a row in parties for sure, you can even remove the `join`.

Comment: VARCHAR !?!?!!?

Comment: The select is suppose to give me the status of an Callcenter Agent, i want to count how many agents (agent_id) in each state (event_id). As the table "events" is just events of the agents i only need to count the latest (with highest value) g_event_id of each agent_id and tricky part is that i only want to count where event_id IN (30, 31, 32, 32, 33).
So basicly, select rows with highest g_event_id (and event_id IN (30, 31, 32, 33)) for each agent_id.

Comment: I think we are getting closer: if I understand you correctly, you want to count: agent 2 is currently in status 31 because of entry 3918, "overwriting" entry 2918, and agent 1 in status 30 (because of 3082). Agent 3 has no relevant last entry (just events with 20-29). So you have 1 agent in 30 and 1 agent in 31. If you would change 8067 (belonging to agent 3) to event_id=30, you would get `(30,2), (31,1)` as a result. Correct? Also, the time is irrelevant, the order is defined by the g_event_id, right?

Comment: Spot on!  Absolutely right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should give you your result:

```
select e.event_id, count(stats.agent_id) as N_count
from (
  select max(p.g_event_id) as g_event_id, p.agent_id
  from events e 
  join event_parties p
  on e.g_event_id = p.g_event_id
  where e.event_id in (30,31,32,33)
  group by p.agent_id
) as stats
join events e
on e.g_event_id = stats.g_event_id
group by e.event_id;
```

The inner query (`stats`) first retrieves the latest relevant status of each agent: it will get the largest `g_event_id` for each `agent_id` with an `event_id` in the given range (so at most one row for each agent).

It will then be joined with the `events`-table to retrieve the actual `event_id` for this `g_event_id`; then it counts the number of agents per `event_id`.

As worked out in the comments, this assumes that `g_event_id` is the primary key for both tables (but especially for `events`), and that the newest status is given by the largest `g_event_id`, not the `event_time`.